Kubuntu 22.04 on MacBook Pro 2011 - updated firmware in Discovery, now it won't boot
I run a dual boot Kubuntu 24.04 on a MacBook Pro 2011. I use rEFInd 0.12.0.
Everything was running fine. Then Discovery popped up with new updates. I just installed them as normal. I noticed it was linux firmware update. Now, my linux partition won't boot.
It gets stuck at this screen
I also see this when I start in verbose mode
